# unit testing with the input and output validation

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin

I am completely new to Unit Testing in Android. I want to write the unit test for a method in my presenter class.

**Sharing the methods need to be covered with unit test**

```
 override fun getRequiredUri(uri: Uri): Uri {
    val moduleName = uri.moduleName
    return when (moduleName) {
        "sample" -> getStandardUriFromSampleUri(uri)
        "application" -> getStandardAppLaunchUri(uri)
        else -> {
            return uri
        }
    }
}

private fun getStandardUriFromSampleUri(uri: Uri): Uri {
    var stringUrl = uri.toString()
    stringUrl = stringUrl.replaceFirst("/sample", "")
    var standardUri = Uri.parse(stringUrl)
    val moduleName = uri.moduleName
    if(moduleName == "application"){
        standardUri = getStandardAppLaunchUri(uri)
    }
    return standardUri
}

private fun getStandardAppLaunchUri(uri: Uri): Uri {
    var stringUrl = uri.toString()
    stringUrl = stringUrl.replaceFirst("application", "link/application")
    return  Uri.parse(stringUrl)
}
```

**I am sharing my test class that I have tried to implement:**

```
class PresenterTest {

   lateinit var presenter: Presenter
   @Mock
   lateinit var mockActivity: Activity
   @Mock
   lateinit var mockUri: Uri

   @Before
   fun setUp() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
       presenter = Presenter()
       presenter.view = mockActivity
   }

   @Test
   fun shouldGenerateStandardUriFromNewUri() {
       val input = Uri.parse("https://example.org/sample/account/edit")
       val expectedOutput = Uri.parse("https://example.org/account/edit")
       val output = presenter. getRequiredUri(input)
       assertTrue(output == expectedOutput)
   }

}
```

This line is getting failed always with class not found an exception.

```
val output = presenter.getRequiredUri(input)
```

Is this the right way to unit test the method? If yes, please suggest the changes that I need to make. If no, then please suggest the alternative ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is occurring at the line

```
uri.moduleName
```

ie: The path segments (uri.patheSegments) are empty while creating a Uri object from test class.

The solution is to run the Test Class with RoboElectricTestRunner.

That is the test class should look like this:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class UriInterceptPresenterTest {

 //-----Test cases-----

}
```